Creating a shortcut executing multiple commands sequentially, in VSCode
It would be convenient if we can excecute multiple commands sequentially with a single shortcut.
For example, to replace a word by copying another, currently I'm doing this:

Select the word under the cursor by ctrl+D; then copy it by ctrl+C.
Then select another word by ctrl+D, then ctrl+V.

In this situation, a shortcut for each procedure above(1. and 2., respectively) would be convenient.
Is there a way to achieve this? I want to do the following, in keybindings.json:
{ "key": "ctrl+d",  "command": "editor.action.addSelectionToNextFindMatch + editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
                    "when": "editorFocus" },

(...which is not possible concatenating multiple commands with +)

The documentation describes this in the doc page "Key Bindings for Visual Studio Code" section "Running multiple commands" using the meta-command runCommands.

It is possible to create a keybinding that runs several other commands sequentially using the command runCommands.

Listed example:
{
  "key": "ctrl+n",
  "command": "runCommands",
  "args": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "workbench.action.files.newUntitledFile",
        "args": {
          "languageId": "typescript"
        }
      },
      {
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "args": {
          "langId": "typescript",
          "snippet": "class ${1:ClassName} {\n\tconstructor() {\n\t\t$0\n\t}\n}"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},

